# Why does multiprocessing.Process can not call a method fom an object instance? can not understand that pickle issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, pickle

I would like to call a method from an object instance as subprocess. I am using python 3.6 on windows 10.

let's create a simple class:

```
class A:
     def __init__(self):
         self.a = "A"
     def run(self):
         print("Hello World")
```

Test it

```
>>> a = A()
>>> a.run()
Hello World
```

Then call the run method through MP

```
from multiprocessing import Process

if __name__ == "__main__":
    p = Process(target=a.run)
    p.start()
```

And then I have the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>   
File "C:\Users\Synerlink\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 105, in spawn_main
     exitcode = _main(fd)
File "C:\Users\Synerlink\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 115, in _main 
     self = reduction.pickle.load(from_parent) 
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'A' on <module '__main__' (built-in)>
```

Can anyone explain me where does it come from an if there is a way to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what your full code looks like, but this just works.

```py
from multiprocessing import Process


class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 'A'

    def run(self):
        print('Hello World')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = A()
    p = Process(target=a.run)
    p.start()
```